# Prepros does not want to automatically compile imported sass file

Tags: compilation, sass, prepros

3 days ago I sent a letter in support, but the answer was never received. I have such a problem. There are several partial sass files that are imported into the main file. In 3 files, the option "Imported file" is in the options, and the main file is automatically compiled when changing in one of the imported files. In the options of a single file, I clicked the "Compile aniway" checkbox and the settings for the usual sass file were opened. But at the same time, the automatic compilation of the main file ceased to work when this partial file was modified. If I make changes, where the options are "Imported files", the autocompilation of the main file works successfully. I would like to clarify how I can return the "Imported file" option for the file that is not being tracked now by FileWatcher? Thank you.

Comment: what is the name of the single file? Is that the main file? Prepos tells you what files are imported by the main file. Recheck all your spelling, the path you use, and follow the sequence of the 3 files. There is probably a spelling mistake or something like that. Do not try to compile partial files

Comment: With the paths to the files, everything is fine. If I compile the main file forcibly by clicking the "Process file" button, then everything is compiled without errors, taking into account the changes in the partial file. If there were problems with the path to the partial file, then the Prepros would produce an error. Moreover, all partial files are in the same directory as the main one, there can in principle be no errors.

Comment: I had the same problem. It didnt produce an error. I found one mistake in spelling and that fixed everything

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I noticed that prepros is case sensitive to detect imported files, although it's case insensitive for compilation. So in main file, if a partial file is imported with incorrect case (in my case first letter was in capital instead of lower case), the file will compile, but partial file is not detected as imported.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this happened when my import statements did not include the underscore.  This would not trigger a recompile :

```
@import "./scss/variables";
```

should be :

```
@import "./scss/_variables";
```